# Continuity of a function with complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, continuity

How could I show if or not the following piece-wise defined function is continuous at the point $z=-i$?

$$f(z)=\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1}, & z \neq -i \\ 0, & z=-i \end{matrix} \right. $$

Comment: hint: $z^2+2iz - 1 = (z - (-i))^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \frac{z^2+2iz-1}{2z^2+iz+1} = \frac{(z+i)^2}{(z+i)(2z-i)}$$

When $z \neq -i$ we have:
$$f(z) = \frac{z+i}{2z-i}$$
Limits as $z \rightarrow -i$ of the denominator and numerator exist, and denominator is nonzero, hence:
$$ \lim_{z \rightarrow -i} f(z) = \frac{\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow -i} z+i }{\lim \limits_{z \rightarrow -i} 2z-i} = \frac{0}{-3i} = 0 =f(-i)$$
Hence the function is continuous.

Comment: Ah right. This is perfect :D So to clarify we are using the algebra of limits for complex functions?

Comment: Yes. We can do so because both limits exist, and the limit of the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I was after! Thanks for the clarification.